# Partial derivative of the trace of matrix entry-wise exponential?

Tags: exponential-function, partial-derivative, trace

Just checking my math here and getting some help for the exponential part.

$\renewcommand{\v}[1]{\mathrm{vec}\left(#1\right)}
\renewcommand{\m}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\trace}[1]{\mathrm{trace}\left(#1\right)}
\renewcommand{\diag}[1]{\mathrm{diag}\left(#1\right)}$
Given that $\m X$ is a $n \times m$ matrix, what does the following partial derivative equal to ?
$$\frac{\partial \trace{\exp(\mathbf X\mathbf X^\top)}}{\partial\m X}$$

We have that $\trace{\mathbf F(\mathbf X)} = \v{\mathbf F(\mathbf X)}^\top \v{\mathbf I}$, so its derivative is $\v{\partial \m F(\m X)}^\top\v{\m I}$.

We also have $\partial \exp f(x) / \partial x = \exp f(x)\partial f(x)/\partial x$.

I guess the partial derivative $\partial \exp \m X \m X^\top / \partial \m X$ must be something like
$$\diag{\v{\exp \m X \m X^\top}}(\m I \otimes \m X+\m X \boxtimes \m I)$$

So in the end, the derivative I'm looking for must be equal to $2\m X^\top\exp(\m X\m X^\top)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final expression is correct in the sense that if $G:X\mapsto\mathrm{tr}(\exp(XX^T))$, then $$\langle\nabla G(X),Z\rangle=2\mathrm{tr}(ZX^T\exp(XX^T))=2\mathrm{tr}(\exp(XX^T)XZ^T).$$ 
Thus, if one identifies the gradient $\nabla G(X)$ with the matrix $M_X$ such that $$\langle\nabla G(X),Z\rangle=\mathrm{tr}(ZM_X),$$ then indeed, the gradient is $$2X^T\exp(XX^T)=2\exp(X^TX)X^T.$$ A more logical convention would be to identify the gradient $\nabla G(X)$ with the matrix $M_X$ such that $$\langle\nabla G(X),Z\rangle=\mathrm{tr}(ZM_X^T)=\mathrm{tr}(MZ_X^T),$$ then the gradient would rather be $$2\exp(XX^T)X=2X\exp(X^TX).$$
The intermediate steps proposed in the question are opaque to me. A direct proof of the result uses simply the characterization of the differential $\nabla G(X)$ at $X$ as the unique linear functional on the space of matrices of size $n\times m$ such that, for every such matrix $Z$ and real number $h$, when $h\to0$, $$G(X+hZ)=G(X)+\langle\nabla G(X),Z\rangle h+o(h).$$

Comment: Can you give me more details about your method to obtain the gradient ?

Comment: What is stopping you when you try to find some $L$ such that $G(X+hZ)=G(X)+hL+o(h)$?

Comment: I know $o(h)$ is supposed to tend to $0$. But, written like that, it looks like it should only depend on $h$.

Comment: ?? $o(h)$ is there to denote any term $A(h)$ such that $A(h)/h\to0$, not only $A(h)\to0$. Can you give me more details about your methods to compute derivatives, in general?

Comment: Right, I forgot about $A(h)/h$. Usually, I do something like this, for example : $\partial trace(XX^\top) / \partial X = (trace(\partial X X^\top) + trace(X\partial X^\top))/\partial X$, then I manipulate the formula to take away $\partial X$.

Comment: Sorry but the approach you describe is horribly non-general.  Do you know any method to compute derivatives, in general?

Comment: I also use an approach where you represent your formula as an expression tree, and apply derivative identities from the top to bottom or from the bottom to the top of the tree. This is described in these slides : http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-pederao/ADTalk.pdf

Comment: Just making sure I understand. If I want to get the gradient of $F(X)=trace(XX^\top)$, using your method, I start with $F(X+hZ)$, realize it's equal to $F(X)+trace(2hXZ^\top)+o(h)$. Then I know I'm interested in $trace(2hXZ^\top)$ and I must work to take $h$ and $Z$ away ? Using $trace(X)=vec(I)^\top vec(X)$ and kronecker products ? Or is there another better way ?

Comment: This is not "my" method, just an application of the *definition* of the differential (which you seem to be lacking, am I right?). In full generality, if $F$ is defined on some vector space, the gradient of $F$ at point $X$ is the linear function $L_X$ such that $F(X+hZ)=F(X)+hL_X(Z)+o(h)$ when $h\to0$, for every $Z$. For $F:X\mapsto\mathrm{tr}(XX^T)$, one gets $L_X:Z\mapsto2\mathrm{tr}(XZ^T)$, hence there is no "work to take $h$ and $Z$ away" to do. What happens is that every linear functional $L$ on some matrix space can be written as $L:Z\mapsto\mathrm{tr}(MZ^T)$ for some matrix $M$, .../...

Comment: .../... hence people (notably, physicists) sometimes identify the linear functional $L$ and the matrix $M$. With this  convention, $L_X$ would be identified to $2X$. Kronecker products are just a pretty artificial way to get equivalent formulas, but they yield no further understanding, if you ask me.

Comment: In fact I know the definition of differential, but sometimes it's kind of confusing for me how to apply this with matrices. What I am truly lacking, however, is that proposition : every linear functional $L$ on some matrix space can be written as $L:Z\mapsto tr(MZ^\top)$ for some matrix $M$. If I get it correctly, by linear functional I must understand a function that maps a matrix to a scalar. And then, every linear functional on some matrix space can be written as a trace because... $tr(MZ^\top)=vec(M)^\top vec(Z)$ ?

Comment: $$\sum_{ij}a_{ij}Z_{ij}=\mathrm{tr}(MZ^T),\qquad M=(a_{ij})$$

Answer (score 1):

The differential of the trace of a scalar function ($f$) with derivative ($f'$) applied to a square matrix argument ($Y$) is 
$$ \eqalign {
 d\,{\rm tr}(f(Y)) &= f'(Y^T):dY \cr
} $$
The exponential function is its own derivative, so $f'=f$ and
$$ \eqalign {
 d\,{\rm tr}({\rm exp}(Y)) &= {\rm exp}(Y^T):dY \cr
} $$
In the case that $Y=(XX^T)$, we have $Y=Y^T$ and
$$ \eqalign {
 d\,{\rm tr}({\rm exp}(Y)) &= {\rm exp}(Y):(dX\,X^T + X\,dX^T) \cr
    &= {\rm exp}(Y):2\,{\rm sym}(dX\,X^T) \cr
    &= 2\,{\rm sym}({\rm exp}(Y)):dX\,X^T \cr
    &= 2\,{\rm exp}(Y)\,X:dX \cr
    &= 2\,{\rm exp}(XX^T)\,X:dX \cr
} $$
The derivative is
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac {\partial\,{\rm tr}({\rm exp}(Y))} {\partial X} &=  2\,{\rm exp}(XX^T)\,X \cr
    &=  2\,X\,{\rm exp}(X^TX)\ \cr
} $$
Where the final equality follows from this general property of matrix functions
$$ \eqalign {
 f(AB^T)\,A &=  A\,f(B^TA) \cr
} $$
where $A,B \in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n}$